# Facebook Marketing API: Potential reach of a Facebook campaign

Tags: python, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-marketing-api

We can run Facebook advert using python SDK. I want to know the potential reach of target audience. Is there any command available or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Reach Estimates of a targeting specification using ad account.

```
account = AdAccount('act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>')
targeting_spec = {
    'geo_locations': {
        'countries': ['US'],
    },
    'age_min': 20,
    'age_max': 40,
}
params = {
    'currency': 'USD',
    'optimize_for': AdSet.OptimizationGoal.offsite_conversions,
    'targeting_spec': targeting_spec,
}
reach_estimate = account.get_reach_estimate(params=params)
print(reach_estimate)
```

**Response Result**

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": 186000000,
    "bid_estimations": [
      {
        "unsupported": false,
        "location": 3,
        "bid_amount_min": 39,
        "bid_amount_median": 80,
        "bid_amount_max": 121
      }
    ],
    "estimate_ready": true
  }
}
```

*186000000 users base on mention criteria*

[Ad Account Reachestimate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/)