# How to get Potential Reach from Facebook Marketing API using Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get the [potential reach](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/reach-estimate/) from the Facebook Marketing API using Ruby on Rails 5. I found the Ruby SDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks/) but I can't see the sample codes nor the functions that I need for getting the data that I want. I also found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722078/facebook-marketing-api-potential-reach-of-a-facebook-campaign) which was based on Python and tried to convert the language to Ruby which led me to this code:

```
require "facebook_ads"

class FacebookApi
  attr_reader :ad_instance

  def initialize(opts={})
    @ad_instance = FacebookAds::AdAccount.get("act_#{opts[:account_id]}")
    raise 'Account ID Key must be provided' unless opts[:account_id]
  end

  def get_target()
    targeting_spec = {
      'geo_locations': {
        'countries': ['US'],
      },
      'age_min': 20,
      'age_max': 40,
    }

    params = {
      'targeting_spec': targeting_spec,
    }

    @ad_instance.get_reach_estimate(params: params)
  end
end
```

However, the function **get_reach_estimate** is not found.

I also tried emulating the sample cURL commands instead and came up with the following test script:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require "erb"
include ERB::Util

class FacebookApi
  def get_target()
    account_id = <ACCOUNT_ID>
    access_token = <USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_WITH_ADS_MANAGEMENT_PRIVILEGE>
    uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_#{account_id}/reachestimate")
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    request.set_form_data(
      "access_token" => access_token,
      "targeting_spec" => url_encode("{\"geo_locations\": {\"countries\":[\"US\"]}, \"age_min\": 20, \"age_max\": 40}")
    )

    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end

    puts response.code
    puts response.body
  end
end
```

Please take note that I'm using the actual account ID and access token in my code. Just hiding it here. So the code above now returns the following error:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID <ACCOUNT_ID> does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "ESJks9/KxJC"
      }
    }
```

I'm sure I added the **ad_management** access to my access token. I also tried removing the prefix *act_* in the URI but same result. I'm hitting a dead-end right now so I would like to ask some suggestions on how to do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's because of the post request. I should be using a GET request instead. Here's the working code for me with the additional **interest** parameter for the targeting spec.

```
def get_target(interest_id, interest_name)
    account_id = @account_id
    access_token = @access_token
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_#{account_id}/reachestimate"

    params = {
      "access_token" => access_token,
      "targeting_spec" => "{" +
          "\"geo_locations\": {\"country_groups\":[\"Worldwide\"]}," +
          " \"age_min\": 20, \"age_max\": 40," +
          " \"interests\": [" +
            "{\"id\":#{interest_id}, \"name\":\"#{interest_name}\"}" +
          "]" +
        "}"
    }

    response = get_response(url, params)

    response
end

def get_response(url, params)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    response = http.request(request)

    response.body
end
```